# TypeError: объект типа «NoneType» не имеет len()

Tags: python, api, type-error

```
"""API."""
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']


def get_links_from_spreadsheet(id: str, token_file_name: str) -> list:
    """
    Возвращает список строк из первого столбца электронной таблицы Google с заданным идентификатором.
Пример ввода с https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WrCzu4p5lFwPljqZ6tMQEJb2vSJQSGjyMsqcYt-yS4M
    get_links_from_spreadsheet('1WrCzu4p5lFwPljqZ6tMQEJb2vSJQSGjyMsqcYt-yS4M', 'token.json')

Returns
    ['https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPszdKAlKCXUhU3r25SOFgBxwCEr-JHVS', ... and so on]
        """
        SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = id
        SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'A1:E'
        creds = None
        if os.path.exists(token_file_name):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(token_file_name, SCOPES)
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    'credentials.json', SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    
            with open(token_file_name, 'w') as token:
                token.write(creds.to_json())
    
        try:
            service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
    
            sheet = service.spreadsheets()
            result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                        range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
            values = result.get('values', [])

        if not values:
            return

        final_links = []
        for x in values:
            final_links.append(x.pop())
        print(final_links)

    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links_from_spreadsheet('1WrCzu4p5lFwPljqZ6tMQEJb2vSJQSGjyMsqcYt-yS4M', 'token.json')
```

При проверке выдает правильный ответ `['https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPszdKAlKCXUhU3r25SOFgBxwCEr-JHVS', 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLH2l6uzC4UEW0s7-KewFLBC1D0l6XRfye', 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0ehjAfLFsp1PGaatzAwo0uK', 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMOpZvQB55bfp6ykOLayLqLrjcpv_Sw3P']`

Но при отправке на тест выдает ошибку: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Я поставил

```
if not values:
            return
```

но видимо дело не в этом. К сожалению доступа к тесту нет, поэтому не могу прислать данные теста. Проводить тесты можно сколько угодно раз.

Comment: А строку и код не показывает, в которых ошибка?

Comment: К сожалению нет, в этом и проблема.

Comment: Ну ошибка явно не в этом цикле, там куда `None` ни поставь, ошибка другая будет. А вы не можете там на каждом шагу разных `print` навтыкать и потом что успевает напечататься посмотреть? Так можно определить где падает. Ну и данные напечатать всякие. И их посмотреть.

Comment: Судя по всему должен быть return, a не print

Comment: Аааа, ну да `-> list:` на это прямо указывает. Ну и вообще. Ошибка скорее всего выходит при проверке результата работы вашей функции.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Разобрался. Поставил все return, в PyCharm перестал выдавать ответ, но тесты прошёл. Всё очень странно.

Comment: Так добавьте `print` к вызову функции, тогда и вы ответ увидите и тесты не должны сломаться )  `print(get_links_from_spreadsheet(...))`

Answer (score 0):

```
"""API."""
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']


def get_links_from_spreadsheet(id: str, token_file_name: str) -> list:
    """
    Возвращает список строк из первого столбца электронной таблицы Google с заданным идентификатором.
Пример ввода с https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WrCzu4p5lFwPljqZ6tMQEJb2vSJQSGjyMsqcYt-yS4M
    get_links_from_spreadsheet('1WrCzu4p5lFwPljqZ6tMQEJb2vSJQSGjyMsqcYt-yS4M', 'token.json')

Returns
    ['https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPszdKAlKCXUhU3r25SOFgBxwCEr-JHVS', ... and so on]
        """
        SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = id
        SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'A1:E'
        creds = None
        if os.path.exists(token_file_name):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(token_file_name, SCOPES)
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    'credentials.json', SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    
            with open(token_file_name, 'w') as token:
                token.write(creds.to_json())
    
        try:
            service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
    
            sheet = service.spreadsheets()
            result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                        range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
            values = result.get('values', [])

        if not values:
            return

        final_links = []
        for x in values:
            final_links.append(x.pop())
        return final_links

    except HttpError as err:
        return err


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links_from_spreadsheet('1WrCzu4p5lFwPljqZ6tMQEJb2vSJQSGjyMsqcYt-yS4M', 'token.json')
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите